# Lots of StandardSession objects in the heap

Tags: java, web-applications, memory-leaks, heap-dump

I am investigating a heap dump for a web application based on java 6 running on Tomcat 6 using eclipse MAT and I noticed that objects of org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession has occupied majority of the heap. Actually there are about 400 objects of the class which has occupied almost 390 MB of the 1.1 GB heap. What is this object used for? Is it normal to have 400 of them in a single web application? Anyway, I am looking for possible memory leaks in the heap.

Thanks a lot
Ferez